# using 1 button to show a different groupbox on each click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a wizard of sort. Like it is one form with 4 groupboxes and one button. The idea is to when the form loads to show groupbox1 then upon each click of the button it would go to groupbox2,3,4

I have tried serveral different things I have found online. from doing `groupbox1.visible =`groupbox1.visible

Nothing has seemed to work. I even tried doing a bool type setup

```
        bool boxon2 = true;
        bool boxon3 = true;
        bool boxon4 = true;

        if (boxon2)
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = false;
            groupBox2.Visible = true;
            boxon2 = false;
        }

        if (boxon3)
        {
            groupBox2.Visible = false;
            groupBox3.Visible = true;
            boxon3 = false;
        }

        if (boxon4)
        {
            groupBox3.Visible = false;
            groupBox4.Visible = true;
            boxon4 = false;
        }
```

if anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple switch statment:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int counter;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // increment counter for whits groupbox you want to show
        counter++;
        switch (counter)
        {
            case 1:
                groupBox1.Visible = true;
                groupBox2.Visible = false;
                groupBox3.Visible = false;
                groupBox4.Visible = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
                groupBox2.Visible = true;
                groupBox3.Visible = false;
                groupBox4.Visible = false;
                break;                   
            case 3:
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
                groupBox2.Visible = false;
                groupBox3.Visible = true;
                groupBox4.Visible = false;
                break;
            case 4:
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
                groupBox2.Visible = false;
                groupBox3.Visible = false;
                groupBox4.Visible = true;
                // set to 0 if counter is 4 so groupbox one will be the next grupbox that will be set to visible
                counter = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice to set the groupboxes property visible as false:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works only thing is groupbox1 is set to true by default so I have to click the button twice to have it go to GB2 so is there a way to avoid the double clicking?

Comment: I figured it out I changes the int counter to int counter=1 and that did the trick Thanks for the help

Comment: Oke nice I've made an update to the post that was my solution so you don't have to click twice.